# xmodem communication over serial port via Tera Term is failing

Tags: serial-port, upload

I'm updating the firmware of transmitters over a serial port using Tera Term. For whatever reason, the upload, via xmodem, keeps failing (or timing out or something along those lines) and I'm trying to figure out why.

I know the transmitter is getting the xmodem receive command because I'm getting the confirmation from it, and the transfer begins. But it always fails between 1% and 15% (others have managed to get it as high as %80). Interestingly enough, it is only this iteration of the firmware that is having this particular problem. Previous versions could be uploaded to the device via the serial port with no issues. On the flip side, the firmware in question can be successfully loaded onto the transmitter directly via a j-link flasher with no problems, so I'm not sure what to make of it.

I've checked the Tera Term [Help Forum](http://logmett.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=2) and numerous other sites, but I couldn't find anything similar. I've also tried messing with the BAUD rate to see if that would affect anything. When talking to my supervisor about the problem, he mentioned that he thought Tera Term had a really low "error limit" where if the transfer had more than something around three or four errors over the course of the transfer it would stop.

My questions, specifically are:

1) Is there a way to raise the error limit for Tera Term?

2) Is there anything else that could be causing this error?

3) Why would a particular firmware be more susceptible to failure than another?

Any answers or plain old advice given is appreciated.

Edit: I monitored the serial port as it was sending the data, and I saw that the transmitter sends an abort right before the update crashes. It stills seems like a serial port/Tera Term problem (I could be wrong about that though) because I can use a flasher to upload the data without problem.